Millisecond time grouping issue
I am currently querying data from a Parquet data lake stored in Azure Data Lake Gen2 via Azure Synapse (Serverless SQL pools) and through Grafana with Microsoft SQL Server as my Grafana data source.
My query looks as below:
SELECT
    DATEADD(SECOND, DATEDIFF(SECOND, '2020', t) / (200/1000.0) * (200/1000.0), '2020') AS time,
    AVG(accelerationx) as AVG_accelerationx
FROM
    OPENROWSET(
         BULK 'https://cssdatalakestoragegen2.dfs.core.windows.net/cssdatalakestoragegen2filesystem/3BA199E2/CAN2_gnssimu/*/*/*/*',
         FORMAT = 'PARQUET'
   ) AS r
WHERE
    t BETWEEN '2020-10-28T14:35:31Z' AND '2020-10-28T14:38:10Z'
GROUP BY
    DATEDIFF(SECOND, '2020', t) /  (200/1000.0)
ORDER BY time
OFFSET 0 ROWS;

This results in data grouped to a 1 second resolution, even though the expected result was data grouped to a 200 ms resolution. The original file is stored at a 100 ms resolution.
The Parquet file I am trying to query is stored as follows in Azure:
https://cssdatalakestoragegen2.dfs.core.windows.net/cssdatalakestoragegen2filesystem/3BA199E2/CAN2_gnssimu/2020/10/28/00000014_00000001.parquet

I have attached the Parquet file in question:
https://canlogger1000.csselectronics.com/files/temp/00000014_00000001.parquet
I assume my query is causing the results to be aggregated to SECOND basis instead of MILLISECOND basis - but replacing SECOND in the query (and directly parsing the 200 ms instead of 0.2 seconds) causes an overflow error as below:

convert frame from rows error: mssql: The datediff function resulted in an overflow. The number of dateparts separating two date/time instances is too large. Try to use datediff with a less precise datepart.


What is the datatype of the column t? Your other value you are comparing it to are varchar literals ( such as '2020'), which would be implicitly converted to a datetime (accurate to 1/300 second). if you want more precision, you should be using a datetime2.

Your division is wrong: https://dbfiddle.uk/NcWGdkbw. $__interval_ms/1000 results in 0 when $__interval_ms is less than 1000.

/1000 => /1000.0 might alleviate the immediate issues of divisions by zero, but i'm not sure about the dynamic stuff you're talking about

Changing to /1000.0 indeed avoids the error. For some reason, however, it seems like the resulting query still aggregates data to 1 second basis, rather than milliseconds, even if the value of $__interval_ms is 1 or 10 for example. I am not sure what I am doing wrong

You might help your cause by providing some example data and expected outputs

I have updated the question now, taking into account the 1000.0 recommendation outlined above and sharing the file and expected vs. observed results

To resolve your] overflow issue, you can use DATEDIFF_BIG(), which returns a BIGINT instead of INT. I believe your code would then be something like SELECT ... DATEADD(MILLISECOND, DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND, '2020', t) / 200 * 200, '2020') AS time ... GROUP BY DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND, '2020', t) / 200 .... If using SQL Server 2022 (or later), you can also use DATE_BUCKET() - possibly DATE_BUCKET(MILLISECOND, 200, t).

DATE_BUCKET is unfortunately not supported via the Microsoft SQL Server data source in Grafana. Similarly, if I try using DATEDIFF_BIG() I get an error saying The query references an object that is not supported in distributed processing mode. - I assume this relates to the fact that Azure Synapse Serverless SQL pools are used, though I am not sure.

Don't add your answer to your question. If you think it's helpful to show us, add as an answer

DATEADD(ms, DATEPART(ms, t) / 200 * 200 - DATEPART(ms, t), t) https://dbfiddle.uk/TKbfopFq

The rounding already happened in the datediff(). The division afterward won't create new buckets.
So just add another level of grouping:
GROUP BY
    DATEDIFF(SECOND, '2020', t),             
    DATEPART(MILLISECOND, t) / 200

To get back the time value add the two components:
DATEADD(MILLISECOND, DATEPART(MILLISECOND, t) / 200, DATEADD(SECOND, DATEDIFF(SECOND, '2020', t)))

One advantage of doing it in separate levels is that the output range of the expressions might avoid or forestall needing to deal with large integers and the potential for overflows. It's also possibly easier to comprehend. On the other hand it could still be worth comparing the query plans to see if the execution is improved with a single value for bucketing and sorting.
Another simplifying assumption here is that your buckets always align with the parent. So a caveat is that you wouldn't be able to just change the divisor to 400, for example, to get increments of 400 milliseconds. From that standpoint this is a disadvantage.
Correcting is still fairly easy and merely requires dividing the seconds portion since the pattern restarts every two seconds now (the least common multiple of 400 and 1000.) A similar calculation deals with the remainder of milliseconds.
GROUP BY
    DATEDIFF(SECOND, '2020', t) / 2,
    (DATEPART(SECOND, t) % 2 * 1000 + DATEPART(MILLISECOND, t)) / 400

The alternate expression offered in comments would become a bit more complicated in such a scenario in the same way. (This actually uses modulus to avoid essentially repeating much of the calculation):
DATEADD(MILLISECOND,
    (DATEPART(SECOND, t) % 2 * 1000
     + DATEPART(MILLISECOND, t)) % -400,
    t)


Can you clarify how this would be used in the broader query?

Thanks for the edit, now I managed to get it working and I have updated my original question with the full query incorporating your suggestion. It works perfectly - thanks a ton!

DATEADD(ms, DATEPART(ms, t) / 200 * 200 - DATEPART(ms, t), t) https://dbfiddle.uk/TKbfopFq

OP's Answer moved from the question
FINAL SOLUTION
Based on the excellent answer by shawnt00, I ended with below query that works and enables dynamic millisecond grouping in Grafana:
SELECT
    DATEADD(MILLISECOND, 
            (DATEPART(MILLISECOND, t) / $__interval_ms) * $__interval_ms, 
            DATEADD(SECOND, DATEDIFF(SECOND, '2020', t), '2020')) AS time,
            AVG(accelerationx) as AVG_accelerationx
FROM
    OPENROWSET(
         BULK '3BA199E2/CAN2_gnssimu/*/*/*/*',
         DATA_SOURCE = 'ParquetDataLake',
         FORMAT = 'PARQUET'
   ) AS r
WHERE
    CONCAT(r.filepath(1), '-', r.filepath(2), '-', r.filepath(3)) BETWEEN CONVERT(date, $__timeFrom()) AND CONVERT(date, $__timeTo())
    AND
    $__timeFilter(t)
GROUP BY
    DATEDIFF(SECOND, '2020', t),
    DATEPART(MILLISECOND, t) / $__interval_ms
ORDER BY time
OFFSET 0 ROWS;




I guess I should note that only the integral factors of 1000 will work if you intend to change out values for the divisor, i.e., the time duration.
